# Bootstrap "Container" inside an <article> tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been adding ,  and  elements to my demo portfolio, just to practice what I've learnt so far, but it seems that these tags mess up the "container" class from bootstrap.
[initial version without accessibility tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PWSl.png)

```
    <!-- <header> -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="hl1"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-3">
                <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="./portrait2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="My Portrait">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Hello there! This is me!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="hl1"></div>
</div>
<!-- </header>
```

As you can see, I've commented out the  tag for the moment. After I add the *header*, *article* and *footer* tags, the content swaps out of the container class and the (hr)tag goes across the total width of the page.
The good part is that the content remains at the same location, like only the (hr)tag would be affected by the tags.

My question is there a way to overcome this? Or I should forget the accessibility tags for now, until I become more advanced in knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: After pumpering with it around, I successfully found out that I only need to modify the location of the (hr) tags and add another "container" class into the (footer) section as well and it looks just great.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you could provide the entire code. Although, you can check if your Bootstrap CDN link is BELOW the link to your external stylesheet. This makes sure that the Bootstrap properties are prevalent over anything you have defined in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I just changed the order in which these appear inside the html file code.